# Why CAsyncSocket does not have copy constructor or = operator?

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, constructor, copy

I have inhereted CAsyncSocket and wanted to pass the objects around.

```
 class ClientSocket : public CAsyncSocket
{
CAsyncSocket nitSocket;
    public:
ClientSocket(void);
virtual ~ClientSocket(void);
 };
```

I get sevaral compile errors when i do

```
 void SomeOtherClass::func(ClientSocket &socket)
     this->socket = socket;
 }
```

Error:

```
'CAsyncSocket::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class          'CAsyncSocket'
```

I looked into file and found

```
private:
CAsyncSocket(const CAsyncSocket& rSrc);    // no implementation
void operator=(const CAsyncSocket& rSrc);  // no implementation
```

Should i make my copy constructor but since there is  no implementation for base class would my code crash at runtime.

Important: Should i make a copy ? WOULD my new object receive the events of original object?

Comment: I don't believe Winsock supports a `dup()` operation. Just change your socket member to be a reference.

Answer (score 0):

[Polymorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) types in C++ are usually made [non-copyable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#Class_noncopyable) because taking a copy of base class easily leads to [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).

Comment: @Fetissov Please answer my questions at the end of body .

Comment: I'm not at all skilled in broken Windows APIs, but I don't believe just taking a copy of a C++ object makes it receive original networking events.

Comment: @Fetissov What about for non-copyable Classes, if i want to derive a class and want to write a copy constructor . How to do it in most efficient way ?

Comment: if windows api is broken what should i use for windows platform ?

Comment: @Ashish, that's the point - you *don't* write a copy constructor for a sub-type of "non-copyable", because it's supposed to be used via pointer/reference and not by value.